# Set administrator rights to program (Windows 10) and have it not ask for permission?

Tags: windows, permissions, administrator, uac

I want to set the programs I normally use and consider safe to always have full access, but it's still annoying how, even set to run as administrator, unblocked and I can personally guarantee are not harmful in any way, Windows will still prompt me everytime I want to open any program already set to run as administrator. Is there any way to avoid this prompt for certain programs set to run as administrator without stopping the UAC? I'd really hope so, because this is truly stupid if there isn't.

This is on Windows 10 with programs set to run as admin and are unblocked -- Windows still asks, "Are you sure you want this unsigned program to make changes to your computer?"

If the program is unblocked, set to admin and I declare it trusted, I shouldn't be prompted to run it.

Comment: If I wasn't sure, I wouldn't have unblocked it and set it to run as admin. It's like a parent sarcastically telling their kid, "Are you sure you want these keys to go drive a car and kill yourself?"

Comment: The thing is, "unblocking" and "setting to run as admin" by themselves aren't admin-only settings... unprivileged programs can set the "Always run as admin" option on a shortcut as well.

Comment: So what's the viable solution? If everything **could** be bad, does that mean security has to be annoying? What's the purpose of unavoidable prompts? It's like patronizing users. A user should be able to launch an administrative program without having to confirm its ability to run at every execution point.

Comment: Windows XP (and all earlier releases) had that. If you were logged in as an admin, everything you ran had admin rights. Didn't end well _at all_. The OS doesn't know whether _you_ are running something, or whether it's _malware_ trying to run something.

Comment: If I understand well, you should have at least one admin account and one separate user account under which all safe applications will run smoothly without any annoying prompts.